# cy.wait("@request") Api call fail

Tags: cypress

My display timeout API call failed. Code:

```
cy.intercept('GET', 'https://docker-intellicon.contegris.com/reporting/report/call_center.........').as('ccrapi') 
cy.wait('@ccrapi')
```

This error is thrown:

```
Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: ccrapi. No request ever occurred.
```

How can I call the display timeout API?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing between your intercept and the wait for the intercept.

You must do something to trigger the request - click a Submit button for example:

```js
cy.intercept(...).as('my-request-alias')

cy.get('button').contains('Submit').click()  // trigger a request that is caught 
                                             // by the intercept set up above

cy.wait('@my-request-alias')           // wait for the interception
  .then(interception => ...)
```